# minimum iOS version for external testers using iTunes Connect / TestFlight Beta Testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

What is the minimum iOS version for external beta testers using iTunes Connect and Apple's new TestFlight Beta testing? (not the old pre-iTunes-Connect TestFlight)

Our app has many users on 4th-generation iPod touch devices which are limited to iOS6, so before we release the new version of our app we want to make sure we get beta test coverage on those old devices.

Comment: Is there any solution for this, any way we can test in iOS7 devices. @Justin Grant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Apple's page:](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

> TestFlight Beta Testing requires iOS 8 or later, and can be used in all 155 countries where the App Store is available.

Answer (score 3):

Although the docs mention the minimum version being iOS 8, the appstore page states it being iOS 13 (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664)

Answer (score 1):

The TestFlight Beta testing app supports only iOS8 and above. So you will be able to install the TestFlight App only in those devices which is running iOS8 and above.

This info can be seen the following page. Check the compatibility section

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/beta), this now is part of [Fabric SDK](https://get.fabric.io) from Twitter. Very good tool, that we use for a long time for Beta distribution, collecting crash reports and analytics. This is totally free.