# Can we use both Apple iOS8 Testflight and HockeyApp for the same app?

Tags: ios, testflight, hockeyapp

Our team recently switched from old-style Testflight to the new iOS8 Apple Testflight. Unfortunately, when we made the switch we didn't realize that [beta testers had to be on iOS8 to install betas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914006/minimum-ios-version-for-external-testers-using-itunes-connect-testflight-beta).

Unfortunately, we have many users stuck on iOS6 because they are using older 4th-generation iPod Touch devices. So we need a beta testing solution for those users, especially since it's older devices where we're most concerned about performance issues as we add features in our new version.

We are considering using HockeyApp for a few iOS6 & iOS7 users to flesh out our beta test matrix. I don't think we'll want to drop Testflight because it seems to have an easier workflow for getting new users into testing-- we'll probably use HockeyApp for a few testers only.

What problems (if any) should we expect from using both beta services for the same app?

Have you tried this combo, and if so what was your experience?

Comment: This is one of those middling questions; although I won't close it. It might be good to start with using both in an application (an internal build, eg.) and seeing how it works - or clearly fails to work. Then there might be a more concrete basis of a "code" question or issue moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try the combo(but already used both), however I am totally sure it will work. You should build an IPA for the HockeyApp and another for the Apple's TestFlight. You shouldn't expect many problems: Just confused testers unsure which beta should they use(and will eventually complain about this). This is the single problem. For avoiding it, you should choose only one(if the old devices performance is important, you should choose HockeyApp for this).

Best regards,

Comment: Good answer, thanks. Re: beta tester confusion, I was assuming that we'd keep them separate-- most testers on Testflight, and a handful on iOS6 & iOS7 using Hockey. As long as we don't send testflight invites to the Hockey testers, will there be a problem?

Comment: None at all. I believe myself this is a good practice for keeping support for the iOS 6 and iOS 7 users and still using recent technologies for the most recent users. Just don't send Apple's TestFlight invitations for the iOS 6 & iOS 7 users and also don't send HockeyApp invitations for the iOS 8 users and everything will be alright.

Answer (score 1):

I used both TestFlight & HockeyApp. They are working fine.

I am sending build to client via Apple TestFlight as well as HockeyApp.

Thanks.